# Where can I find a 1/2" bit screwdriver?

Tags: tools

I have a 3/8" bit screwdriver but the bolt I need to unscrew is even bigger than that and TIGHT, so using that screwdriver is starting to strip the screw a bit.  I can't find a bigger one anywhere online.

Comment: A picture would be a nice addition to this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [one from Grainger](http://www.grainger.com/Grainger/WERA-Chiseldriver-Screwdriver-6ANN5).

Sounds like you might need to use some frozen-bolt techniques, too (penetrating oil, carefully applied heat, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a job for a socket wrench. [image]

Because a socket wrench has a long handle, it acts like a lever and you can get a huge amount of torque from it, MUCH more than you can get from a screwdriver.

You can get driver bits for those as well, but since you said 'bolt' and it's 1/2", that it will have a hex head on it that you can use a socket bit on.

Using some penetrating oil or WD-40 on the threads may also help to loosen it if it's rusted or corroded.

Comment: It's for a screw that isn't accessible via a socket wrench. It's part of a pump assembly.

Comment: Even with an extension bit (you can get them anywhere from 6"  to a couple feet long)? I'd need to see a picture before I can provide any more suggestions